# IHttpClient implementation within Orleans.NET

Tags: orleans

Usually, it's [recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) to create a wrapper implementing `IHttpClient` or `IHttpClientFactory`. Meanwhile, some Orleans [samples](https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/1.5/Tutorials/Interaction-with-Libraries-and-Services.html) show that it's ok to create `HttpClient` instance on-demand and use it directly from the grain.

**Questions**

- Should I create Orleans service as a wrapper around `IHttpClient` or call HttpClient directly from the grain?
- If I need a wrapper, would this implementation suffice?
- What's the difference between `GrainService` and `GrainServiceClient`?

```
public interface IRemoteGrainService : IGrainService
{
  Task<T> Get<T>(string source) where T : new();
}

public class RemoteGrainService : GrainService, IRemoteGrainService
{
  private IGrainFactory _grainFactory;
  private HttpClient _remoteService;

  public RemoteGrainService(
    IServiceProvider services,
    IGrainIdentity id,
    Silo silo,
    ILoggerFactory
    loggerFactory,
    IGrainFactory grainFactory) : base(id, silo, loggerFactory)
  {
    _grainFactory = grainFactory;
  }

  public override Task Init(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
  {
    return base.Init(serviceProvider);
  }

  public override async Task Start()
  {
    _remoteService = new HttpClient();

    await base.Start();
  }

  public override Task Stop()
  {
    _remoteService.Dispose();

    return base.Stop();
  }

  public Task<T> Get<T>(string source) where T : new()
  {
    return JsonConvert
      .DeserializeObject<T>(
        await _client.GetAsync(source))
          .Content
          .ReadAsStringAsync);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should follow standard best-practices when using `HttpClient` within Orleans. The sample is creating a new one for simplicity of exposition, not as an indicator of best practices. A PR to change the sample documentation to use `IHttpClientFactory` (for example) would likely be accepted.

You do not need a `GrainService` to call into HTTP services from your grain: you can inject the required dependencies (`IHttpClientFactory` or your typed client) and call HTTP services directly from grain code.

Regarding the question on the purpose of `GrainService` and `GrainServiceClient`, `GrainService` is a special service which is intended to be accessed from grain code. `GrainServices` are instantiated on every node in the cluster and each one is given responsibility over a set of grains. As an example, reminders (persistent timers) in Orleans are implemented using `GrainService`s. The `LocalReminderService` on each node takes responsibility for a set of grains and will wake those grains up when their reminders are due. `GrainServiceClient` is used by grains to access the `GrainService` instance which is responsible for the calling grain. The documentation explains more here: https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Documentation/grains/grainservices.html

I would avoid using `GrainService` unless you find a use case which it fits closely.